# C code needed for launch exe when F10 or Hotkey key is pressed

Tags: c, timer, static

can anybody tell me exact code

i have this code. im using devc++ and i need only C code.

````````````````````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    
system("C:/programA.exe"); // how to add 2nd program with timer?
 return 0;
}

```````````````````

This code works ok.


Step1- launch Program A immidiately. (already in mentioned code works).Then goto next line without waiting to close ProgramA.
Step2-  sleep for five seconds
Step3-  launch Program b (Only if user press a key F10 or F11)
With waiting time 30 seconds.

If user not press that key then close automatically after 30 seonds.
````````````````````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *Fork* the program and use [execvp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) to replace the forked process with the program you want to start.
- Detecting key presses directly is not possible using just C. The `ncurses` library is a good general choice to do this.

Comment: can u please tell me code for my purpuse.. ites not running.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not how Stack Overflow works. Show that you've made significant effort at finding a solution yourself and ask specific questions, only then we can help you. [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: im not a programmer . u know solution and it will take one minute for you. mine  for 7 days. please help. and on stackoverflow there are many comments that shares a code. please help. i beg u

Comment: @haseakash Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Writing this would take a significant amount of time from me as well. Your best bet may be to go on a different website to hire a programmer to do the work for you.